# Using undefined in Typescript

Tags: typescript, undefined

I have the following function definitions

```
function getX1(): string | undefined { ... }

function getX2(): string { ... }

function myFunc(x: string | undefined): MyClass | undefined {
    if (x === undefined) return undefined;
    return { ... };
}

function consume(val: MyClass) { ... }
```

`myFunc` is guaranteed to only return undefined if `x` is undefined.

Scenario 1:

```
const x1: string | undefined = getX1();
const res1 = myFunc(x1);
if (res1) {
    consume(res1);
}
```

Here, I want the caller to make sure the result `res1` is not undefined before continuing.

Scenario 2:

```
const x2: string = getX2();
const res2 = myFunc(x2);
consume(res2);
```

Here, I don't want to add the same overhead for the caller. This snippet currently gives me a compiler error. I can't figure out how to avoid the undefined check without using `!`. Is there a way to have typescript enforce this rule for me?

Comment: Please provide code for getX1/getX2 or share code in TS playground

Comment: The implementation of getX1 and getX2 doesn't matter much. getX1 returns `string | undefined`, getX2 returns `string`. I've added this clarification above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to tackle this issue:

```js
function myFunc(x: string): MyClass;
function myFunc(x: undefined): undefined;
function myFunc(x: string | undefined): MyClass | undefined {
  if (x === undefined) return undefined;
  return {  };
}
```

You can define the exact return types separately (undefined returning undefined and string returning MyClass). This helps the compiler understand what happens when you pass a certain value to it.

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8C%20BYAULgZgK4B2wALgJYD2x0AtvAGInAAUAHgFzQRkBOFYgHMAlNwTJIEANwEWlGvSYsO3EgBMApvkGb1Y6Bu271snEVILaDZqVU9%20godAA%20h4lp3E9I9LmjQFPjQHNAAvBHunia%20fJpkhHy0Rl56ZgFxCUnoARjQkHBIKDK42Hjm8tS0wDQQhHSarABuYCDiRVK%20aND%200DXEEFQgmgB0IFRCza0iZmW4-bzQ7ABM3LwCwuHQAOQQ22YLZNBxEMtbNiorM-O19Y0nyzNAA)

and you can find an explanation on Overloads [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) (thanks @jcalz for pointing this out)

LE:

Ideally you should be able to do something like this, using conditional types:

```
function myFunc<T extends string | undefined>(x: T): T extends string ? MyClass : undefined {
  if (x === undefined) return undefined;
  return {  };
}
```

Unfortunately, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30152) exactly about this problem and typescript incorrectly narrows conditional types. Until that is fixed (still isn't as of 4.1) you should use function overloads.

Comment: Consider providing a link to the documentation on [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) in TS, which is what the answer is using.

Comment: Hmm seems like this doesn't work when the parameter being passed in is of type "string | undefined". It needs to either be "string" or "undefined" for this to work.

`Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)`

Comment: Adding a third overload that explicitly takes string | undefined seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The solution will work, just to give you a hint on how to improve readability in typescript.

**Use typeof**

Use always `typeof === "undefined"` if you want to check for undefined values explicit. There are some edge cases where `prop === undefied` is not working as you would expect.

**Avoid undefined**

If you use `undefined` you probably want also to check for null values in your control flow.

Prefer `null` instead of undefined it is more explicit and easier handle in control flows.

Here a quick suggestion for your code example

```
function getX1(): string { ... }

function getX2(): string { ... }

function myFunc(x: string): MyClass {
    if (typeof x === "undefined") return null;
    return { ... };
}

function consume(val: MyClass) { ... }
```